# How to send a file in the background while a chat works in C#

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm creating a chat with C# and sending texts works very well, but I'm not sure how I can send a large file through the tcp flow using packets without disturbing the flow of text messages.

Is it possible to send more than one information through the flow? separating what is text from what is file being received?

Comment: I would think that you could either a) establish a secondary connection for sending the file or b) send the file in parts, where each chunk is a different kind of message to regular chat messages.

Comment: can please share the approach you have tried so far along with block of code.